# PC doesn't recognize television

Tags: hardware-failure, hdmi, tv

I have a Sony Bravia tv that I need to connect to my computer. When I try to connect it to my laptop it works fine. However, when I try with my standard PC it doesn't even recognize.

The laptop is about 1 year old and has WAY lower specs than my PC so what am I doing wrong?

Here is a list of my PC specs:

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 8/6/2013, 21:27:30
       Machine name: MARC-PC
   Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.130318-1533)
           Language: Danish (Regional Setting: Danish)
System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
       System Model: System Product Name
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 11/09/12 10:59:44 Ver: 15.02
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.4GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8144MB RAM
          Page File: 4057MB used, 12229MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA
          Chip type: GeForce GTX 670
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1189&SUBSYS_841B1043&REV_A1
     Display Memory: 4042 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 1994 MB
      Shared Memory: 2048 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1200 (32 bit) (59Hz)
       Monitor Name: Standard PnP-skærm
      Monitor Model: BenQ V2400W
         Monitor Id: BNQ7B03
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1200(p) (59.950Hz)
        Output Type: HD15
        Driver Name: nvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um
Driver File Version: 9.18.0013.2049 (English)
     Driver Version: 9.18.13.2049
        DDI Version: 11
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.1
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 6/21/2013 14:06:36, 15144928 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
    WHQL Date Stamp: 
  Device Identifier: {D7B71E3E-52C9-11CF-F27B-16A41CC2C435}
          Vendor ID: 0x10DE
          Device ID: 0x1189
          SubSys ID: 0x841B1043
        Revision ID: 0x00A1
```

Comment: How is the TV connected to the system? Is it the only monitor when it's connected, or is it a secondary monitor? Does it show up in **Control Panel > System > Device Manager > Monitors** ?

Comment: What is the max resolution and refresh rate you can use when connecting a PC, and what res/refresh does the laptop use when connected, and have you tried setting the PC tl match that?